# In python's sqlite3 module, will using cursor.fetchone() as the condition for a while loop fetch a row?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python's sqlite3 module.

I want to iterate through the rows in my table until none are left.  I want to do this one at a time instead of using `fetchall` because the table is quite large. I read in the python sqlite3 documentation that `curs.fetchone()` returns `None` when no rows are left in the cursor's selection.

So I had the idea to run my code in a `while fetchone():` loop, with the 'actual' `fetchone()` call occuring inside the loop, like so:

```
while c.fetchone():
    row = c.fetchone()
    print(foo(row))
```

I can't tell if this loop is actually fetching a row once in the while statement and once in the body, or if it is only in the body. Which one is it?

Comment: Fetching one at a time will give you the opposite problem: Sure, you don't pull down everything at once, but you will make a lot of hits to the database.

Comment: How would the cursor know the difference between the "actual" `fetchone` call and the one in the `while` condition? `fetchone` doesn't know where it's been called from. You just run `fetchone` twice, only keeping the second result, effectively skipping every other row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will execute `fetchone` twice so it is not a good idea. Since `sqlite3.Cursor` is iterable you do something like this:

```
for row in c:
    print(foo(row))
```

Alternatively you can use infinite while loop and fetch data in batches using [`fetchmany`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany):

```
# Lets take  1000 rows at the time
batch_size = 1000
while True:
    rows = c.fetchmany(batch_size)
    if not rows: break
    for row in rows:
        print(foo(row))
```